# How to read a logo and image files in www folder of an R Shiny app inside a docker container?

Tags: r, docker, shiny, dockerfile, shinydashboard

I have created a R shiny app, which has a few logos and images (favicon.ico, company logo etc.) stored in the www folder in the app.
I am added COPY statements for all files and I am checked the running container, the files are there. But the Shiny app itself is not being able to read the files and show the logos.
When I run locally, the images are being displayed correctly.

EDIT: MORE CONTEXT: I am not using `fluidPage`, but using `dashboardPage` from the `shinydashboard` package.

Here is my Dockerfile.

```
# Base R Shiny image
FROM rocker/shiny

# Make a directory in the container
RUN mkdir /home/shiny-app
RUN mkdir /home/shiny-app/www
RUN mkdir /home/shiny-app/files

WORKDIR /home/shiny-app

# Install R dependencies
#################

# Copy the Shiny app code
COPY app.R /home/shiny-app/app.R
COPY files/* /home/shiny-app/files/
COPY www/* /home/shiny-app/www/

# Expose the application port
EXPOSE 8180

# Run the R Shiny app
CMD Rscript /home/shiny-app/app.R
```

I am bulding as: `docker build -t shiny-analysis-app .`
I am running as: `docker run --rm -p 8180:8180 shiny-analysis-app`

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that your `app.R` looks like this:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("bins", "Number of bins:", min = 1, max = 50, value = 30)
        ),
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("distPlot"),
           img(src='cat.png', align = "right", width="50%"),
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white',
             xlab = 'Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)',
             main = 'Histogram of waiting times')
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

It includes an image `cat.png` from the `www/` directory. Testing on the host works fine.

Now your `Dockerfile`.

```
FROM rocker/shiny

RUN rm -rf /srv/shiny-server/*

WORKDIR /srv/shiny-server/

COPY app.R ./
COPY files ./files
COPY www ./www
```

No need to explicitly run the script. Just put it into the server directory.

Now build and run.

```bash
docker build -t app .
docker run --rm -it -p 3838:3838 app
```

Then open http://127.0.0.1:3838/ in your browser.

[image]

Comment: Your code is working, however, mine still doesn't work. One difference between yours and mine is that you are using a fluid page, while I am working with the dashboard page from the `shinydashboard` package. Do you think that is causing the problem?

Comment: Share a minimal version of the app which exhibits the problem.